# Automation using Putty

Tags: sql, unix, batch-file, automation, putty

I'm trying to automate few things I do routinely. I'm looking to use PuTTy as the command line client and work out a few things.

I currently doing this command:

```
start C:/%username%/Desktop/Putty.exe -ssh root@server.name 22 -pw password -m command_file.
```

The server operations includes logging into a RSH and then to SQL prompt, logging out of SQL and then logging out of RSH, and then logging into another RSH and then a different SQL prompt.

I used the logic of using a batch file with unix commands, but it isn't working.

My commands file looks something like this:

```
rsh -l username SERVER1
password
sqlplus owner/admin
select *...
update *...
commit;
logout
logout

rsh -l username SERVER2
password
sqlpus owner/admin
select*..
update*..
commit;
logout
logout

exit //close the putty session.
```

But this code isn't working. Only the initial UNIX commands are executed and the rest of the code is ignored.

Someone please provide a solution to take this forward.

Answer (score 0):

Your script doesn't have any way of differentiating between the bash commands and the input to sqlplus.  You could use a here document:

```
...
sqlplus owner/admin << HERE
select *...
update *...
commit;
HERE
logout
...
```

Comment: I don't know sqlplus so I'm running blind here.  Have you tried opening a putty window and entering the individual commands manually?  That would ensure you have no syntax errors at least

Comment: Yes, I use these commands on a daily basis. Its just that the file isn't read completely at all. It just goes into rsh and stays there. The SQL code isn't executed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your answer is in your question. You pass a command file to PuTTY for processing. Have you tried passing a command file to sqlplus?

I'm personally unfamiliar with the syntax  but it sounds like [this poster](http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php/topic,7395.msg32488.html?PHPSESSID=08e9afdbfc980d875ab2160c83f0dfa7#msg32488) is not. Looks like the syntax you want is

```
sqlplus Username/Password@DatabaseName as SYSDBA @c:\mystuff.sql
```

Though your command file will need to be on the remote server rather than on the local machine like the PuTTY script.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently made some putty shortcuts automation / ease of access on windows. This may help you guys.

-create a folder XYZ in C:\User%USERNAME%\XYZ

-user must have Write access in this folder to avoid HostNotFound error

-place putty.exe in it

-place a text command_file.txt containing few commands i.e. ls -lrt; sleep 10; logoff

-create a windows shortcut wiith following configuration

--Target :
C:\User%USERNAME%\XYZ\putty.exe -ssh Vm0000xxxx -m "C:\Users%USERNAME%\command_file.txt -t -loghost "Terminal_Title"

--Start in : C:\Users%USERNAME%\XYZ

--Icon : %USERPROFILE%\XYZ\icon.ico